# как ответить на сообщение пользователя от имени бота ? telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

на данный момент бот работает только так

1. пользователь пишет сообщение боту
2. бот отправляет мне(администратору) сообщение

и вот как ответить на сообщение пользователя от имени бота ?
то есть надо через в боте ответить на сообщение и чтоб бот отправил сообщение именному тому пользователю, который писал сообщение, а таких пользователей может быть несколько

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('________')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет❗\nНапиши мне вопрос:")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def forward_message(message):
    bot.forward_message(chat_id='________', from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='✅ Вопрос отправлен!')
    bot.send_message(chat_id='________', text=f'Новое сообщение от пользователя {message.from_user.id}.')

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0) #обязательная для работы бота часть
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого стоит создать новую команду

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['answer'])
def send_answer(message):
    command = message.text.split(' ',2)
    user_id = command[1]
    answer_text = command[2]
    bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=answer_text)
```

Теперь если отправить боту команду в формате: `/answer [id] [answer]`, где `id` это telegram id пользователя которому направляется ответ, `answer` - весь текст ответа.

Например: `/answer 7318283891 Да, я получил твой вопрос, держи свой ответ`

Answer (score 0):

Вначале в коде добавь такую переменную:

```
to_chat_id = <id твоего аккаунта в ТГ в цифрах>
```

А под ней вот это:

```
needHelp = []
```

Далее создай файлы needHelp.txt и team.txt (в последний так же добавляя свой id в цифрах)
Вместо того, чтобы просто отслеживать текст, сделай его отправку через команду, например:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['messagetocreator'])
def newidea(message):
    needHelpFile = open("Местонахождение файла 'needHelp.txt' в памяти компа", "a")
    if message.chat.id > 0:
        needHelpFile.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n" + str(message.chat.first_name) + "\n")
    else:
        needHelpFile.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n" + str(message.chat.title) + "\n")
    needHelpFile.close()
    supportFile = open("Местонахождение файла 'team.txt' в памяти компа", "r")
    supportTeam = set()
    for line in supportFile:
        supportTeam.add(line.strip())

    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
            'Чуть-чуть подождите, {0.first_name}! ' +
            'Мы уже отправили Ваше сообщение ДОБРЫМ АДМИНАМ, ' +
            'скоро они Вам ответят.\nНе присылайте. пожалуйста, ' +
            'больше сообщений, без необходимости'.format(
                 message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')
    for user in supportTeam:
        if message.chat.id > 0:
            bot.send_message(int(to_chat_id),
                             str(message.chat.id) + " (" + message.chat.first_name + ")" + ": " + message.text[
                                                                                                  message.text.find(
                                                                                                      ' '):])
        else:
            bot.send_message(
                int(to_chat_id), 
                str(message.chat.id) + " (" + message.chat.title + ")" +
                ": " + message.text[
                                                                                                        message.text.find(

                                                                                                            ' '):])
    supportFile.close()
```

Таким образом люди, отправившие тебе сообщение записываются в файл needHelp.txt, а тебе приходит сообщение с именем и id отправителя.
Если ты не знаешь свой id, то просто сам в этот бот отправь что-нибудь, введя что-то по типу этого:

```
/messagetocreator Привет!
```

Дальше берёшь и копируешь циферки из файла needHelp.txt и вставляешь их в переменную to_chat_id.

После этого, чтобы ты смог отвечать на сообщения людей, напиши такой код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['answer'])
def answer(message):
    supportFile = open("местоположение файла 'team.txt' в памяти твоего компуктяра", "r")
    supportTeam = set()
    for line in supportFile:
        supportTeam.add(line.strip())
    supportFile.close()
    if str(message.chat.id) in supportTeam:
        needHelp = []
        needHelpFile = open("местоположение файла 'needHelp.txt' в памяти твоего компуктяра", "r")
        for line in needHelpFile:
            needHelp.append(line.strip())

        needHelpFile.close()
        for user in supportTeam:
            if message.chat.id > 0:
                bot.send_message(user, str(message.chat.id) + " (" + message.chat.first_name + ")" + ': Answering to ' +
                                 needHelp[0] + " (" + needHelp[1] + "): " + message.text[
                                                                            message.text.find(' '):].format(
                    message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')
            else:
                bot.send_message(user,
                                 str(message.chat.id) + " (" + message.chat.title + ")" + ': Ответил ' + needHelp[
                                     0] + " (" + message.chat.title + "): " + message.text[
                                                                              message.text.find(' '):].format(
                                     message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')
        bot.send_message(int(needHelp[0]), 'Создатель этого бота отвечает Вам' + ": " + message.text[message.text.find(' '):])

        with open("местоположение файла 'needHelp.txt' в памяти твоего компуктяра", "r") as nhf:
            lines = nhf.readlines()
        with open("местоположение файла 'needHelp.txt' в памяти твоего компуктяра", "w") as nhf:
            for line in lines:
                if line.strip("\n") != needHelp[0] and line.strip("\n") != needHelp[1]:
                    nhf.write(line)
    else:
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            "К сожалению Вы не можете ответить".format(message.from_user,
            bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')
```

Таким образом, отвечать сможешь только ты и не вводя id вручную, как в другом ответе. Отвечать надо так:

```
/answer Привет!
```

А человек будет получать:

```
Создатель этого бота отвечает Вам: Привет!
```

Надеюсь, что помог)))